# Uglify - javascript error coming using the uglified clubbed file

Tags: javascript, node.js, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am using grunt to club various javascript files and minify them all. e.g

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        uglify: {
            build: {
                src: ['js/jquery-1.7.min.js','js/common.js','js/drop_down.js', 'js/main_jquery.js', 'js/tooltip.js', 'js/html5shiv.js','js/MathJax/MathJax.js','js/angular-1.2.15.min.js','js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.js'],
                dest: 'js/output.min.js'
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
```

On using `output.js` in place of src files, I am getting surprising javascript errors.

e.g.This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly.

I am curious to know how does `uglify` deal with variables with same name in two files. What could all be the reason for javascript errors?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use the `concat` task instead?  I tend to use `concat`, then `uglify` the result of that.

Comment: Hi James, As suggested I now used concat to create one clubbed file and then used this file as input to uglify. There is no error on using concatenated file. However, using the uglified file is giving the same error.

Comment: ok - so definitely an issue with the uglify process then rather than it being a problem with the concatenated files

Comment: How can I go about debugging the issue with uglify?